# Insert rows based on insert statement (nested insert)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

A common insert statement is this..

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (ID) VALUES (1)
```

What I wanted to achieve is to Insert an ID using another insert statement from another table.. It would look like this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES (INSERT INTO tbl_name2 (ID) VALUES (1))
```

I have tried it but it's giving me errors..

```
INSERT INTO tblReport_OPA (ID_Main) VALUES (INSERT INTO tblReport_OPF (ID_Main) VALUES (1))
```

I'm currently developing under vb.net 2010 and sql express 2005

Comment: I urge you to not try and use 2 `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can use [OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblReport_OPF (ID_Main) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.Id_Main
    INTO tblReport_OPA
SELECT 1 as Id_Main
```

Note you'll have to use *SELECT* instead of *VALUES*

Answer (score 0):

Opyionally a merge can be used.

```
merge into #a T1
using (select -1 as ID)Q on Q.ID=T1.ID
WHEN NOT matched by target then
insert(id) values(1)
output
inserted.id
INTO #b;
```